# Is the IMG pixel required when creating Standard and Custom Events in Facebook Pixel?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was recently made aware that facebook has changed the way they track conversion. The new Facebook Pixel introduced the possibility of adding events to the page.

I´ve read [through the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/api-reference) and also the guide to [install the Facebook pixel with Google Tag Manager](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1021909254506499?helpref=hc_fnav). However, I have a question regarding the IMG pixel at the end of the code. Is it strictly necessary when I send an event? Or just calling `fbq('track', 'eventName', {customData});` would be enough?

I want to do an implementation using GTM. My goal is to have a Tag with the Base Code that fires in all pages and other event tags that fire in some events. My set up would use the Tag Sequencing option on GTM.

My question is would a Custom HTML Tag like this would suffice?

```
<script>

    fbq('track', 'eventName', {customData});

</script>
```

Or MUST I include the IMG pixel? If I must include it. What should be in it? I could not find any documentation about it.

I hope I´ve made myself clear.
Thank you very much

Comment: The image is the fallback mechanism to have at least some basic tracking for users that don’t have JS enable.

Comment: I see. And is there a documentation on how to set it?

Comment: The code generator already generates it for you, so what do you need documentation on?

Comment: It genarates a IMG url for the pageview track(src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={{facebookId}}&ev=PageView&noscript=1"). However I´m trying to implement custom events and pass custom data and I have no idea how the IMG url should look like for that.

Comment: Check out the examples in the documentation, there you can clearly see how different events and if needed additional data are passed as parameters in the image URL.